# Ionic 3 shows error 400 while adding platforms

Tags: ios, cordova, npm, ionic3

I am trying to migrate from one system to another. Thus have cloned the code from my git repository on my system and now am trying to deploy an application from my new system. So as am trying to add platforms for the same thus I have executed the `npm install` command successfully and now when I try to run the `ionic cordova platform add ios` but the command ends up with an error with error code 400 exact error is as follows :

```
> cordova platform add ios --save
✔ Running command - done!
> ionic cordova resources ios --force
✔ Collecting resource configuration and source images - done!
✔ Filtering out image resources that do not need regeneration - done!
✔ Uploading source images to prepare for transformations - done!
✖ Generating platform resources - failed!
Error: encountered bad status code (400) for https://res.ionic.io/api/v1/transform
body: {"Error":"source image 1015x1015 too small for Default-736h.png, requires at least 1242x2208 source file"}
    at Response.res.on (/My Drive/ionic_app/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/lib/cordova/resources.js:148:32)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at Response.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1056:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

I tried replacing the images but the issue is persistent. Unable to figure out the issue.My current operating system is macOS High Sierra. However the code works fine when executed in ionic lab environment using `ionic serve -l`

Comment: The same code works fine on my previous machine.

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Comment: Still working on the same but unable to solve it.

Comment: Did you try by replacing the splash screen to be of 2732×2732px?

Answer (score 0):

If you execute `ionic cordova resources --help` you'll notice that the output says something like:

> [...] The source image for splash screens should ideally be at least
>   **2732×2732px** and located at resources/splash.png [...]

So in order to fix it you'd need to replace the `splash.png` file (in the `resources` folder) by a new splash image of `2732×2732px`.

Then run `ionic cordova resources` again and it should be fixed.